# Parsing JSON Response in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

My web app returns a JSON object. I am simply trying to write the result to a page and the best I can get is 'undefined'.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 var text= [
  {
    "name": "xx",
    "street": 65.2067810799497698,
    "phone": 134.2967768940979501
  }
];


alert(text.name)

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
text.name 
;
</script>
```

Comment: remember in this case `text` is in square brackets - so try `text[0].name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to parse anything, just change `text` to `text[0]` whenever you are trying to get your value (name, street...) from the first index which is `0`

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 var text= [
  {
    "name": "xx",
    "street": 65.2067810799497698,
    "phone": 134.2967768940979501
  }
];

alert(text[0].name)

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text[0].name 

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSON.parse(text)`.

**[EDIT]**:

`JSON.parse(text)` would parse `text` **had it been a string response**.

In your case, you have an **object inside an array**, so add a `[0]` to `text` like another answer correctly points out as shown:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text[0].name;
```

Since this array has **only one object nested**, you are safe with that without having to loop for different indices.

Comment: I started with this, but I think it's a JSON object not a string in JSON format

Comment: JSON.parse ?? but why ?

Comment: I thought he couldn't parse the string. I'm updating @John.